# 'svn diff' not showing differences for deleted files under directory

Tags: svn, delete-file, diffstat

I have directory structure as below in svn

```
Dir1/file1
    /file2
    /file3

Dir2/file1
    /file2
```

I have deleted the directory `Dir1` and committed the changes to svn using `svn rm Dir1` and `svn ci -m"deleted dir" .`. If I check the svn log I can see that the folder is deleted.

```
#svn log -v .
...
D /path/Dir1
```

But when I take the svn diff, it is not including the files that I deleted. where as if I delete the file then svn diff shows the deleted file content as well.

```
#svn diff -r5937 .
#
```

So, how to get the file difference for the files which are deleted under a directory using `svn diff` command? this is required because I am using `diffstat` command to see the overall change (number of files, number of lines added, number of lines deleted) between two revisions.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any direct svn way of doing it.
Since I have committed the changes, svn is not able to show the diff for the files inside the folders.

But I could achieve it with another checkout. I took one new checkout with the older revision (where the folder is not deleted) using `svn co -r<N> <link>` and then did `svn rm Dir1`. 
Now without committing the changes I took the svn diff which showed the required changes.